# Windows Phone Webbroswer is not rendering content correctly?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Windows phone Webbrowser is not rendering the content correctly. For example the Euro symbol is showing as special character "***(euro (€)***". Is there any way i can show the actual content like this in WebBrowser?

Comment: You've probably got an encoding issue. Please show what you're trying to display.

Comment: using WebBrowser.NavigateToString("<html><Body><table><tr><td>(euro (€)</td></td></table></body><html>") This what iam trying to do and there are plenty of other characters will be there

Comment: hi matt, i read your article and i understood the issue. Output is coming from an api and how to find and replace  numeric unicode characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

```
StringHtmlContent = StringHtmlContent.Replace("€", "&euro ;"); //between &euro and ; no whitespace
```

Or, in your case:

```
using WebBrowser.NavigateToString("<html><Body><table><tr><td>(euro (&euro ;)</td></td></table></body><html>")
```